# Glide not working on different devices, FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I´m getting strange behavior from the app I'm developing. Normally I run it on a Pixel 2 XL, but now I'm testing it on other devices and APIs. With the Pixel 2 Xl and API 27 I'm getting no errors whatsoever, but changing to other APIs and/or devices I get following:

```
Load failed for https://cryptocompare.com/media/12318177/ada.png with size [60x90]
                                                                        class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
                                                                        There was 1 cause:
                                                                        java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://cryptocompare.com/media/12318177/ada.png)
                                                                         call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                                          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
                                                                        There was 1 cause:
                                                                        java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://cryptocompare.com/media/12318177/ada.png)
                                                                         call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                                            Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://cryptocompare.com/media/12318177/ada.png

01-16 14:25:16.522 4661-4661/com.example.patrickhaller.cryptofolio I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
                                                                        java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://cryptocompare.com/media/12318177/ada.png
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                                                                            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:106)
                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:59)
                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:299)
                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

To clarify, here the used Glide lines:

```
 val glideUrl = GlideUrl(baseUrl + url)
 Glide.with(context)
         .load(glideUrl)
         .transition(withCrossFade())
         .into(holder.logo!!)
```

I also tried it with Volley, instead of Okhttp.

Comment: I can confirm this issue on Nexus 6 (Android 7.1). In my case you url (https://cryptocompare.com/media/12318177/ada.png) is working fine, but i get the same stacktrace with this url https://plus.google.com/_/focus/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECMan_fCfk6D3_wEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKig4ODFjODdkMzMwY2FiYjE5Nzg1MDQ1NWQ5YTk1MTg5YWE4MDg0Yzk5MAGf0v2AKBI5sPoLdJLX5aQPIU4GpQ

Did you have any luck solving the problem?

Comment: For me it  is working fine now, sorry its been a while from there, so I'm not sure.  Do you also use the GlideUrl class to set url? Maybe it had to do with url handling? Are you using the glide debugging feature?

Comment: I tried String, Uri and GlideUrl with the same result. Ill see about the debugging feature, thanks.